# Open or download URL link in Grails Controller

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to render or download a URL that links to a PDF in a Grails controller method. I'm okay with either opening this is in a new or the same tab, or just downloading it. How is this done in grails?

So far I have:

```
render(url: "http://test.com/my.pdf")
```

However, I get errors with this and other ways I've tried, such as rendering a response with content. Any clues?

Comment: You want to download the target of a URL in a controller. And possible store it locally (on the server) and then serve it? Or you want to display the user a link to a PDF? And probably publish that PDF via Grails?

Comment: I'm fine with just an automatic download to the 'Downloads' directory. Like, when you click on any link on a page, and it automatically downloads it

Comment: I am not sure you can do that. It would be easier to have the request return JSON (like `render([url: "http://test.com/my.pdf"] as JSON)`) and on the client side have Javascript to open the link (`window.open(response.url);`)?

Comment: @AlexandraMirtcheva who should download it to "Downloads" dir? user or server? where this "Downloads" dir is, on user computer on on same server where Grails app is running?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov the Downloads directory would be on the client side, so the user.

Comment: @Ivojnovic That is a really good solution as well, might end up going with that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is

```
class ExampleController {
    def download() {
        redirect(url: "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf")
    }
}
```

Going to `localhost:8080/appName/example/download` will, depending on the users browser preferences, either download the file or open the file in the same tab for reading.

I works with grails 2.5.0

Comment: I ended up going with `render (url: "http://test.com/my.pdf"] as JSON` in the controller, and then in the javascript, I set `window.location = url` and that just downloaded it instantly.

Comment: That was the better choice, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can absolutely do it easily:

First get the file from the URL (if you don't have a local file) for example:

```
class FooService {

    File getFileFromURL(String url, String filename) {
        String tempPath = "./temp"     // make sure this directory exists

        File file = new File(tempPath + "/" + filename)
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)
        fos.write(new URL(url).getBytes())
        fos.close()
        file.deleteOnExit()

        return file
    }
}
```

Now in your controller, do this to allow user to automatically download your PDF file:

```
class FooController {

    def fooService

    def download() {
        String filename = "my.pdf"
        // You can skip this if you already have that file in the same server
        File file = fooService.getFileFromURL("http://test.com/my.pdf", filename)

        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "${params.contentDisposition}; filename=${filename}")
        response.outputStream << file.readBytes()
        return
    }
}
```

Now as the user will hit `/foo/download` the file will be dowloaded automatically.

Comment: I can download my file. But i need to show my PDF file in new tab, What should i do now and where can i get the URL?